# How to add legends to scatter graph of core plot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I am using core plot graph in my iphone application. How to add legends in scatter graph. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
graph_.legend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph_];
graph_.legend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor darkGrayColor]];
graph_.legend.cornerRadius = 5.0;
graph_.legend.swatchSize = CGSizeMake(25.0, 25.0);
graph_.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
graph_.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0, 12.0);
```

Comment: can u tell how to add legendTitleforscatterplot?

Comment: Do you want to add text to legends? It can be done by setting title property of each CPTScatterPlot added to the graph. If you do not give a value as title, coreplot will display the identifier property of each plot as the text in legend.